# Display specific static block based on two or more applied filters - magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I have the following code, but it does not work.

```
        <?php $appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State')->getActiveFilters();
        if (is_array($appliedFilters)) {
            foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
            if ($item->getFilter()->getRequestVar()) {

            switch ($item->getFilter()->getRequestVar()) {

            case ('attribute_1') :
                $_displayStaticblock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('static_block_1')->toHTML();
                break;
            case ('attribute_1') && ('attribute_2') :
                $_displayStaticblock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('static_block_2')->toHTML();
                break;
            case ('attribute_1') && ('attribute_2') && ('attribute_3') :
                $_displayStaticblock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('static_block_3')->toHTML();
                break;
            }
            }
            }
        echo $_displayStaticblock;  
        }
        ?>
```

I need to display specific static block based on applied filters, but I do not know how to do it. Please help!

Comment: try var_dump($appliedFilters).r u getting any result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think placing switch case inside loop is incorrect.try this.Please let me know if it works for you.

```
$_filters=Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State')->getActiveFilters();
$filterName=Array();
 foreach($_filters as $filter)
{
$filterName[]=$filter->getFilter()->getRequestVar();

}
if (in_array("color", $filterName)&& in_array("size", $filterName) && in_array("sleeve_length", $filterName)) {

    echo "3";
}else if(in_array("color", $filterName)&& in_array("size", $filterName))
{
echo "2";
} elseif(in_array("color", $filterName))
{
echo "1";
}
```